# How to pass structured data from jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Here's my code in jQuery

```
    function link() {


        var items = $.map($('.trSelected', grd), function (i) {
            return i.id.substr(3);
        });

        // alert(items.length);
        // alert(items.join(', '));


        $.ajax({ url: '/Pos/Link', type: 'POST', datatype: 'json',
            data: ( { PosId: '@Model.PosId', PosDetailIds: items } ),
            success: function (result) {
                grd.flexReload();                    
                alert('saved.');
            }
        });


    }
```

Here's my code in ASP.NET MVC controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Link(PosLink posLink) 
    {

        var svc = ServiceWirer.GetTxServiceInstance();
        svc.Pos_Link(posLink);

        return Json(new { HasError = false });
    }
```

For reasons unknownst to me, only the PosId is populated, the PosDetailIds is not populated

**[UPDATE]**

@Raynos:

I even tried this, but no go too:

```
public JsonResult Link(Guid PosId, Guid[] PosDetailIds)
```

Only the PosId is populated, the PosDetailIds is still null

Here's the PosLink structure:

```
public class PosLink
{
    public Guid PosId { get; set; }
    public Guid[] PosDetailIds { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show us your definition of `PosLink`. `PosDetalsIds` should be `String[]`

Comment: try passing your data like this `data: ('PosLink' : { PosId: '@Model.PosId', PosDetailIds: items } ),`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it now, I used jQuery's $.param

```
  $.ajax({ url: '/Pos/Link', type: 'POST', datatype: 'json',
        data: $.param( { PosId: '@Model.PosId', PosDetailIds: items }, true ),
        success: function (result) {
            grd.flexReload();                    
            alert('saved.');
        }
    });
```

Way much better:

```
  $.ajax({ url: '/Pos/Link', type: 'POST', datatype: 'json',
        traditional : true, // jQuery folks love PHP/Ruby very much :-)
        data:  { PosId: '@Model.PosId', PosDetailIds: items },
        success: function (result) {
            grd.flexReload();                    
            alert('saved.');
        }
    });
```

Rationale found here: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-1-4-breaks-asp-net-mvc-parameter-posting

Comment: This is great, previously I'd been using the json2 plug-in and calling .stringify on the list.  This works even better.

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind JSON to method parameters out-of-the-box. [See here for a solution](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) using ValueProviders.

Comment: Actually, you get this out of the box in MVC3 if you're using the latest version. I stand corrected.